# Is every knot unavoidable in the embeddings of some graph?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, knot-theory, ramsey-theory

> Is it the case that, for any given knot $K$,
>   there exists some graph $G$ whose every embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$
>   (or into $\mathbb{S}^3$)
>   contains a cycle that realizes $K$?

I know the famous Conway-Gordon result that the complete graph
on seven vertices $K_7$ is intrinsically knotted in that every
embedding contains a knotted cycle.
And Joel Foisy proved that $K_{3,3,1,1}$ is also intrinsically knotted
(*J. Graph Theory*, 2002, [ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1380507)).

Instead, I am asking a Ramsey-like question: 
Whether it's known that, for every particular knot, there exists some
graph for which that particular knot is unavoidable.

Comment: Trivial observation: since every graph is a subgraph of a complete graph, it suffices to consider complete graphs for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.** See this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-324-02/S0002-9947-1991-1069741-9/S0002-9947-1991-1069741-9.pdf) of Negami.  The main result is that for any fixed knot (or link) of type $k$, there is a constant $R(k)$ such that every straight line embedding of $K_{R(k)}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains a knot (or link) equivalent to $k$.

Comment: Very nice! But usually the notion of intrinsic knottedness relies on tame embeddings, rather than specifically straight-line embeddings.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke a generalisation of [Fary's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem) should be able to show these equivalent.

Comment: Certainly you cannot allow arbitrary embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^3$, because then you could embed each edge as a local knot and the theorem would be false.

Comment: Does it make sense to ask whether, allowing arbitrary embeddings, there must be a cycle realising a knot which is the connected sum of $K$ and some other knot?

Comment: Negami obtains an upper bound on $R(k)$, but, as he says in his final sentence, this bound "is not however so worthy" because it depends upon as-yet unknown values of Ramsey numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no for the following silly reason.  Take any graph $G$ and some embedding into $\mathbb R^3$.  To any edge, we may perform the connected sum with a fixed knot $K'$ (that is, take a small straight part of the edge and connect sum to it $K'$ there).  Do this operation separately to all of the edges.  Then any cycle in $G$ has knot type of the form $K'\#(\text{something})$.  We just need to pick a knot $K'$ so that the given $K$ is not of this form.

We could modify the question and ask whether a fixed knot $K$ exists in some weaker sense in any given embedding of $G$.  One such (very) weak sense could be that there exists a knotted torus $T$ in knot type $K$ and a cycle in $G$ which is contained in $T$ and cannot be made disjoint from a compressing disk for $T$.  I suspect this may also have a negative answer, however.  It seems one can probably always find embeddings of $G$ which are arbitrarily complicated, and in particular which are not related in any way to the given knot $K$.

Comment: Tony Huynh said it first.